# Apache Rewrite with a Domain Extension Variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite all `/base/` paths to a domain but with an unknown domain extension. Also removing any subdomains as well.

For example:

```
subdomain.domain.com/base/some-path → domain.com/some-path
domain.ca/base/some-path → domain.ca/some-path
```

*Note the different domain extensions which remain constant.*

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/base/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.%{DOMAIN_EXTENSION}/%1 [L]
```

Is there a way to collect the domain extension?